# Proving $\cos(4x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1$ without using LHS and RHS

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

> Prove that
> $$\cos(4x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1$$

**My Attempt**
$$\Rightarrow \cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x) =8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1$$
Add 1 to both sides
$$\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x) +1=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+2$$$$\Rightarrow \cos^2(2x)=4\cos^4(x)-4\cos^2(x)+1$$
$$\Rightarrow \cos^2(2x)=(2\cos^2(x)-1)^2$$ $$\Rightarrow \cos^2(2x)=(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))^2=(\cos(2x))^2$$
$$\therefore \cos(4x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1$$

My professor says that this is an invalid proof as it was not proven using LHS and RHS and assumed that they were equivalent to add 1 to each side. My question: are there any proofs that would not work if you assumed that the two side were equivalent? Any examples will be much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah your professor is right. Your proof is backwards lol

Comment: Your proof is completely fine because every step can be reversed. You just need to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:  $$8\cos^4x-8\cos^2x+1=1-8\cos^2x\sin^2x=1-2\sin^22x=\cos4x.$$
Also, we can use your idea:
$$\cos4x=2\cos^22x-1=2(2\cos^2x-1)^2-1=8\cos^4x-8\cos^2x+1.$$

Comment: What about that proof that makes it invalid?

Comment: @hwood87  You need to prove that $\cos4x=8\cos^4x-8\cos^2x+1.$ But you took the last equality and proved that $\cos^22x=\cos^22x.$ It's not exactly, that you need to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not wrong, it's just backwards. You need to start with $\cos^2(2x) = \cos^2(2x)$, then do the same manipulations you did in reverse order to end up with $ \cos(4x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1$.

But your question is can a backwards proof ever be wrong? Yes it can. Consider this very simple "proof" that $1=2$:

(1): $1=2$

(2): $1*0=2*0$ (multiplying both sides by 0)

(3) $0=0$

$\therefore 1 = 2$.

Comment: However would the proof be invalid if addition was used?

Comment: The reason why my above "proof" is wrong is because a) it is backwards, and b) it involves multiplication by 0 which does not have an inverse. In other words to make the proof valid, we need to reverse the backwards proof, which would involve reversing the multiplication by 0, which isn't possible (that's the definition of not having an inverse).

Comment: Now you are asking if a proof is a) backwards, and b) involves addition, then could it be invalid? In the real numbers, the answer is no, it would always be valid, because addition can always be reversed using subtraction. Addition always has an inverse. In fact a backwards proof in any number system is valid if it only uses operations that are reversible in that number system.

Comment: However, to get real nitty gritty, there are number systems where addition does not always have an inverse. Such an example is wheel theory (which ironically does allow you to divide by 0). Specifically addition by the number $\frac{0}{0}$ is not reversible in wheel theory. So a backwards proof that involves addition would not be valid in wheel theory.

Comment: Moral of the story, just don't write your proofs backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea can work but it's not very well-explained. You want to show

$$\cos(4x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1.$$

You first apply the double angle formula on the RHS, so it suffices to show

$$\cos^2(2x)-\sin^2(2x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+1.$$

Now you don't like the $\sin^2(2x)$ so you replace it with $1-\cos^2(2x)$ so that it suffices to show

$$2\cos^2(2x)=8\cos^4(x)-8\cos^2(x)+2.$$

Now you can divide both sides by $2$, rewrite the RHS as a square, apply another double angle identity, and arrive at the tautology $\cos^2(2x)=\cos^2(2x)$.

The important thing from the logical point of view is that all your steps need to be two-way, in order to *prove* the desired statement *from* the tautology and trig identities, rather than assuming what you want to show and deriving a tautology.  Thus you should not write $\Rightarrow$ in a derivation like this, since it makes it look like your steps are one-way when they're actually not.

If you're going to connect your statements with arrows at all, they should probably be $\Leftrightarrow$ (in principle $\Leftarrow$ would work too, but that would be a very weird way to explain things). Alternatively, you can write some steps in the reverse direction and then reverse all the steps to write your actual proof (which is also helpful for making sure that each of your steps really is reversible).

Answer (score 0):

Well your proof is not "wrong" because each of the step you did was two way ie. Each of the two consecutive steps were equivalent. You should start at last step of you "argument". This "method" is often used in schools to prove some trivial logarithmic inequalities. But remember that this "method" doesn't work in general. Each of the steps must be reversible. So start the proof from the last step.